# How to put multiple graphs in one plot with ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

#### Sample data:

```
y1 = c(1,2,3,4)
y2 = c(6,5,4,3)
x  = c(1,2,3,4)
df = data.frame(x,y1,y2)
```

#### My Question:

I would like to combine the following two graphs into one, using `ggvis`:

```
df %>% ggvis(~x,~y1) %>% layer_paths()
df %>% ggvis(~x,~y2) %>% layer_paths()
```

However, the following does not work:

```
df %>% ggvis(~x,~y1) %>% layer_paths() %>% ggvis(~x,~y2) %>% layer_paths()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can refer to the original data and add a layer:

```
df %>% ggvis(~x,~y1) %>% layer_paths()%>%
  layer_paths(data = df, x = ~x, y = ~y2)
```

[image]

You can remove the reference to the data and it will be inferred:

```
df %>% ggvis(~x,~y1) %>% layer_paths()%>%
+     layer_paths(x = ~x, y = ~y2)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but it's rather unfortunate that you can't use the pipe language to do it.

Comment: E.g. I expect the following to work but it doesn't: `df %>% ggvis(~x,~y1) %>% layer_paths() %>%
  {  df %>% ggvis(~x,~y2) %>% layer_paths() }`

Comment: You can remove the reference to the data and it will be inferred. I see nothing unfortunate what you have written is neither clear nor intuitive you are piping a list to a list and expecting?

Comment: ok, that's much better, thanks! :) As for "you are piping a list to a list and expecting", the way I understand the pipe is logical sequences of operators that occur one after another. The way I visualised my pipe operation was sensible from my perspective.

Comment: So one x,y pair goes in ggvis and another goes in layer_path(). This is a good example of a bad api design

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to merge two ggvis by merging together each of their components:

```
p1 <- df %>% ggvis(~x,~y1) %>% layer_paths()
p2 <- df %>% ggvis(~x,~y2) %>% layer_paths()

pp <- Map(c, p1, p2) %>% set_attributes(attributes(p1))
```

I don't know if it works well in all situations, but it works at least for simple plots.

Here is a function that will do it for you:

```
merge_ggvis <- function(...) {
  vis_list <- list(...)
  out <- do.call(Map, c(list(`c`), vis_list))
  attributes(out) <- attributes(vis_list[[1]])
  out
}
```

You can use it with objects containing plots:

```
merge_ggvis(p1, p2)
```

or in a pipe:

```
df %>%
  ggvis(~x, ~y1) %>% layer_paths() %>%
  merge_ggvis(
    df %>% ggvis(~x, ~y2) %>% layer_paths()
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it possible to handle situation with different axes, So p1 is layer_points with y=y and axis orient = left;  and p2 is layer_lines with y=log(y) and axis orient right. I may have to post separate question